# Floating-point operation error bounds

Tags: floating-point, theory, ieee-754

Given the equation `ax^2 + bx + c`, we know that the discriminant `D = b^2 - 4ac` tells us if the equation will have two distinct roots `D > 0` , one repeated root `D = 0`, or no real roots `D < 0`. Clearly, if the discriminant is zero, then an error could make it either positive or negative, depending on where the error is greater.
Prove that if the discriminant is nonzero, then no error in the floating-point calculation can flip its sign (i.e., from positive to negative, or from negative to positive). Can an error make the discriminant equal to zero?

I know this has little to do with actual programming but exactly how do i show that it is impossible that for `floating point calculation error of the discriminant` to cause a positive discriminant D to somehow become negative and vice versa.

Comment: I'd say it has a lot to do with programming, since it's about the possible errors you can get with a floating point representation.

Comment: well i said actual programming as in coding. This isn't homework, more like a proffesor's way of making us suffer by giving us advanced questions that we can never do without getting help

Comment: Just some observations: `b^2` is always non-negative.  Unlike two's-complement integers the sign is stored separately in floating-point representation, so you can't get 'accidental' sign changes due to overflow.

Comment: Can somebody fix the title too ? I don't see how that has anything to do with the problem...

Comment: "This isn't homework, more like a professor's way of making us suffer by giving us advanced questions that we can never do without getting help" -- that certainly sounds like homework, and if you can't do the homework without help, you should be going to **office hours**, not asking someone else to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

1. The statement is not quite true as written.  It depends on the properties of *binary* floating-point arithmetic, and would necessarily not hold if the calculation were performed in a different radix (it does not hold, for example, in IEEE-754 decimal floating-point).  This is, admittedly, an extreme corner case, and not something I would expect to be discussed in an undergraduate course.  However, it's also a hint, which I why I point it out to you.
2. Catastrophic cancellation does not play a role.
3. The proof follows almost immediately from the basic properties of binary floating-point arithmetic.

That's all I'm saying, because this is clearly homework.  If you want to post your attempt at a proof, I'll be happy to offer suggestions, but I won't just do your work for you.

Finally: get used to being confronted with homework that you don't know how to do, especially in theoretical CS or mathematics courses.  If you knew how to do it already, you wouldn't be learning anything, and what would be the point of that?

**Edit:** Eric Postpischil is correct that the statement is also false for certain edge cases even in binary arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

The claim that, if evaluating the discriminant yields a non-zero result, it has the same sign as the mathematically exact discriminant is not true. Since this is a homework problem, I will not say more for now, except for a hint: Consider that underflow or overflow may occur even if the final result would not be outside the range of floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it has to do to the fact that checking if the determinant is positive or negative is really checking whether `b^2` is greater than or less than `4ac`.

In both cases, you are multiplying two numbers, so the error would be the (similar) ? Seems like that's the kind of reasoning you are looking for.

But taking the case to the extreme, if for example your numbers are floats and the "error" is actually just using integers, then it is possible to change the sign :

a=2, b=2, c=2/3

The determinant is : D = 2^2-4*2*2/3 = -1.333

Taking the error, it is rounding c to 0 and the determinant becomes : D = 2^2 - 0 = 4

If that's too extreme, you can divide all those coefficients as much as you want, it is still the same equation and with a smaller error, you should get the same result...

**More...**

Maybe the answer is that what Tim described, there is cancellation when the numbers are very different from each other (and the one much smaller is pretty much ignored), that cannot change the change of the difference.

So if `abs(b^2)` for example is much greater than `abs(4ac)` then the determinant will be the sign of `abs(b^2)`... and vice-versa.

Comment: that extreme case u have shows that it is possible to have negative to positive discriminant, so then wat it would be a reason for that to not happen

Comment: Wat I mean is how is it possible that u can never have an error that flips the sign because thats wat the question is saying. Really confused

Comment: well, I am just saying the question is wrong... and I give you an example where it can happen...

Comment: lol the question isnt wrong, i'm in university, and my prof isn't an idiot when he comes with these questions. BTW do u know about catastrophic cancallation, maybe that will help.

Comment: Catastrophic cancellation is when significant errors occur due to floating-point representations.  For example, `1e20 + 1e10 == 1e20` and `1e15 + 1 - 1e15 == 0`.  In this latter case, the error is infinite.

Comment: I am not saying your professor is an idiot... just trying to answer your question. And no, I don't know about catastrophic cancellation, but I know about errors induced by rounding.

Comment: Guess I'll have to ask the prof how to do this. damn he really is so damn tough with these questions, even top notch people such as u guys aren't able to help. Thanks anyway.